# module.exports SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, discord.js

It's been an issue with my code for a while. I wanted to put my currency commands in a separate file, but I can't figure out how to fix the error `await is an async function`. If there's a way to make all the code in the file read async that would be amazing, but otherwise just a way to make the await in the module work would be awesome.

One of the commands:

```
//coins.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'balance',
    execute(message, args){
        var output = await eco.FetchBalance(message.author.id)

        const balembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.avatarURL)
        .setTitle(`${floweremote} | ${message.author.username}'s Balance`)
        .setDescription(`${floweremote} ${output.balance}`)
        .setColor(0xFF8AFF)
        .setFooter(`Akasuki ${version}`, client.user.avatarURL)
        .setTimestamp(new Date());            
        message.channel.send(balembed);
        }
    }
```

How I load the code:

```
//index.js
if (command === 'balance') {
    client.commands.get('balance').execute(message, args);
}
```

Spread throughout the file (coins.js) are other lines with `await` and they all have the same issue, of course. I understand what's wrong, I just don't know how to fix it. Sorry if the question looks silly.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Well, you can put `async` in front of your `execute()` method as in `async execute(message, args) { ... }` and then you will be allowed to use `await` in that function.

Comment: Or, you can use `.then()` instead of `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can put `async` in front of your `execute()` method as in:

```
async execute(message, args) { ... }
```

and then you will be allowed to use `await` in that function.

Or, you can just use `.then()` instead of `await`.